# Do we need "instead" in the title "Track a tag badge instead"? Should it be put dynamically depending on the choice?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, user-experience

We've got two options for tracking the progress:

- to track a privilege
- to track a tag badge

When the first option is selected, the UI looks fine:

[image]

When the second option is chosen, it feels like "instead" is inappropriate there:

[image]

The solution, I would like, is putting "instead" at the end of the opposite option dynamically.

Otherwise, it can be removed from the second option.

What do you think?

**UPDATE:**

I've checked out Stack Overflow на русском, it's alright:

[image]

Comment: would a radio symbol be better?

Comment: IMO, if it stays as a tick, the word "instead" should move to the other option as you suggest. If it changed to radio buttons then the word "instead" should be removed.

Comment: The word 'instead' should be removed altogether - it's unnecessary.

Comment: @AndrewMorton That request reminds me a lot of pluralisation bugs. I'm expecting Jeff Atwood to come around any moment now and threaten you with coming to your house and beating you to death with a giant "instead" sign. :P

Comment: @Siguza Are we suggesting it should be changed to two radio button?

Comment: @AndrewMorton no, but you're suggesting that the "instead" should hop between the two options dynamically.

Comment: @Siguza It was the OP who suggested that originally.

Answer (score 25):

[As Kirk Broadhurst suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363041/do-we-need-instead-in-the-title-track-a-tag-badge-instead-should-it-be-put?cb=1#comment555777_363041), the simplest solution would be to remove "instead" altogether.

[image: User page without "instead"]

Comment: this *seems* like a small code change that really gives the user experience a "crisp" feel. Your's and Kirk's suggestion might be a simple solution, but [at what cost?](https://media.giphy.com/media/zDyVp3FAkfkI0/giphy.gif).
 I'm personally in favor of making the change

Comment: @MattR Most "small" code changes come with [not-so-obvious challenges](http://alistapart.com/blog/post/the-most-dangerous-word-in-software-development). For example: the code would need to be tested and translated for [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), and [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: That could easily take 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @MarkWragg ...as it should. I never trust a feature or even hotfix developed in less time.

Comment: In the long term that will save the Internet GBs of traffic.

Comment: or add "instead" to "track my next privilege" when unselected ? :)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro, Russian SO titles are good